# What are the advantages of using '&' over '<' in bindings/scope in angular 1.5 when passing a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With 1.5 angularjs promotes components and composition as the way to structure your app. Sometimes you need to pass a function into a child component. There are 3 different binding types that allow you to do so: '&', '<', '='. I'm aware of how they work, but I don't see why would I use the '&' binding anymore, when the '<':

- makes it easier to pass functions down the hierarchy (without the clunky object-to-args syntax)
- makes it easier to detect if the function was passed at all (with the '&' binding the function always exists, so simple checks like `!this.myFunction` will not work)

Yet, many tutorials and books still show the '&' as primary way of passing functions to components, so I imagine there must be some advantages of using '&' instead of '<'. What are they?

To further clarify my question. Imagine I have a parent component that wants to pass a function (a callback) to its children. The children are supposed to be reusable components, that work well with or without said callback.

If `ChildA` specifies the binding type of callback to be '&', it has to call it with the `$ctrl.callback({ data: data })` syntax and it is unable to simply check whether the callback exists (say I want to only show a certain button if the callback is available).

On the other hand, in ChildB the binding type of callback is '<'. Parent passes the function same as any other value. Advantages of this approach are that the ChildB calls the function with more natural syntax (`$ctrl.callback(data)`) and is able to check for the function existence in very simple way: `<button ng-show='$ctrl.callback'>Only shows when the callback fn is available</button>`.

So, to outline the question once again: why would I even use the '&' anymore?

Comment: Isn't the age the reason here? You're correct, '<' is only available since 1.5, and most of those tutorials were written well before that release.

Comment: I doubt it: current docs (1.5.9, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component ) for component still specify that the "outputs are realized with & bindings, which function as callbacks to component events".

Comment: Looks like you've already found your answer. Both follow input/output paradigm from A2, & works in the opposite direction from < and is basically an alternative to scope events (which don't exist in A2).

Comment: I disagree. Both '&' and '<' (and '=' i guess, but it allows changing the function, so it might be not exactly desired) can be used for output: pass in a function and call it in the child component.

Comment: Ah, see what you meant here. For me, the reason for _outputs_ is that those are simply endpoints - sort of a 'reverse API' of a component, and it's the customer of the component who decides how exactly this API will be used. For example, how'd you replace `on-update="$ctrl.update('location', value)"` in that doc you've shown? `value` is known to the client of the component, but not to the component itself, and it's hardly convenient to `<` an instance of `$ctrl.update` bound by `value`.

Comment: Much like in plain JS, or maybe more common in react: `this.onUpdateLocation = this.update.bind(this, 'location')`, or use function composition, so: `this.update = field => value => { ... }; this.onUpdateLocation = this.update('location');`.

The issue here is using it in the view since returned functions aren't strictly equal, but that could be solved with, say, underscore's memoize function.